# Do inbound gifted monies require a credit unlock?

Tags: scams, credit, pension, gifts

My credit has been frozen for the last 20 years and I unfreeze when necessary. I am being told that I need to unfreeze my credit in order to receive these funds. Why would my credit need to be unfrozen to receive funds from someone's pension?

Answer (score 41):

It wouldn't. This sounds like a scam. Especially since you haven't explained why anyone else's pension would be sending money to you.